# CMD.exe: Move files to a folder shortcut

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Here is my folder structure:

```
destination.lnk
file.1
file.2
file.3
file.4
```

How can I move these files with the command line to "destination" without having to type out the whole path?

```
move file.* destination.lnk
Cannot move multiple files to a single file
```

Comment: You can make an environment variable for this. Like %ProgramFiles%, it will automatically route to the desired location. Go to "System" in Control Panel, click "Advanced system settings", click "Environment Variables", click "New", make a variable name, click "Browse Directory" and navigate to the folder, or paste the destination folder there. Then reference it using %variablename%

Comment: You have to extract the destination directory from the shortcut. There is no easy way to do this in `cmd`, but see [How can I parse a .LNK shortcut from the Command Prompt in Windows?](//superuser.com/q/806932) for one possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because you're trying to move two files into the single link file, and you can't do that.

Instead, I would recommend you to save a target path to a variable and move files to its casted value:

```
SET location=C:\your_folder
move file.* %location%
```

EDITED:

As I understood, you wish to store the location to the target folder in a separate file. So you may simply replace the shortcut you have with a text file containing target path:

```
set /p location=<destination.txt
move file.* %location%
```

Comment: Wouldn't I still have to type out the whole path to set the variable?

Comment: In the second case, you can save the path to the file which is quite similar to the shortcut approach you suggested

Comment: Using the second approach - If I set the location to destination.txt, it can't find the file because a .txt doesn't exist.  If I set the location to destination.lnk, the actual variable stores "L"

Comment: first, you create a file containing the path you want to move your files to, i.e. using Notepad you put the line "C:\your_folder" to the `destination.txt`. Once the file is in your current folder, the command will find the file

Comment: But if I create a text file, I will still have to somehow type out or copy/paste the entire path, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get what you want. In some sense, the shortcut is also the path to a particular folder - in a different format. If you want to hide the path, you put it into the file and secure with permissions. What's the point trying to use a shortcut? How is it any better than a file with a path?

Comment: The point would be to have a short command to type out, since I have to do this multiple times within a directory.  In Windows Explorer, I can select and move to a link.  I thought there might be a way to do that with the command prompt as well

Comment: @divided I made a quick response, if you're willing to use PowerShell. Otherwise, check out the link posted on your original post's comment chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symlink

```
mklink Destination "C:\Users\All Users\Dokumente"
```

and then

```
move file.* Destination\
```

the trailing backslash is important as the symlink itself can't be the target.

The symlink will show up in a dir like sys:

```
> dir des*
 Volume in drive C is System-Xxxxx
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-xxxx

 Directory of c:\Test

06/26/2017  18:33    <SYMLINK>      Destination [c:\Users\All Users\Dokumente]
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  89.795.506.176 bytes free
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use PowerShell, here's a script to do exactly what you want, while keeping it encapsulated in a variable:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = '.\shortcut.lnk'
$TargetPath = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath
```

Then use that variable in PowerShell to achieve what you want.